# How to create custom set accumulator, i.e. Set[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, accumulator

I am trying to use custom accumulator in Apache Spark to accumulate in a set. The result should have Set[String] type. For this I creat custom accumulator:

```
object SetAccumulatorParam extends AccumulatorParam[Set[String]] {
    def addInPlace(r1: mutable.Set[String], r2: mutable.Set[String]): mutable.Set[String] = {
        r1 ++= r2
    }

    def zero(initialValue: mutable.Set[String]): mutable.Set[String] = {
        Set()
    }
}
```

Yet I can not instantiate variable of this type.

```
val tags = sc.accumulator(Set(""))(SetAccumulatorParam)
```

result in error .Please help.

```
required: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam[Set[String]]
```

Comment: What you did looks quite different from the official documentation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators). I'm also skeptical about the usage of an object here as I would assume Spark would want to instantiate this accumulator at some point.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Traian's answer, here is a general case SetAccumulator for spark 2.x.

```
import org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2

class SetAccumulator[T](var value: Set[T]) extends AccumulatorV2[T, Set[T]] {
  def this() = this(Set.empty[T])
  override def isZero: Boolean = value.isEmpty
  override def copy(): AccumulatorV2[T, Set[T]] = new SetAccumulator[T](value)
  override def reset(): Unit = Set.empty[T]
  override def add(v: T): Unit = value + v
  override def merge(other: AccumulatorV2[T, Set[T]]): Unit = value ++ other.value
  override def value: Set[String] = value
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
val accum = new SetAccumulator[String]()
spark.sparkContext.register(accum, "My Accum") // Optional, name it for SparkUI

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "a", "b", "c")).foreach(s => accum.add(s))

accum.value
```

Which outputs:

```
Set[String] = Set(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for 1.6:

```
object StringSetAccumulatorParam extends AccumulatorParam[Set[String]] {
    def zero(initialValue: Set[String]): Set[String] = { Set() }
    def addInPlace(s1: Set[String], s2: Set[String]): Set[String] = { s1 ++ s2 }
}

val stringSetAccum = sc.accumulator(Set[String]())(StringSetAccumulatorParam)
sc.parallelize(Array("1", "2", "3", "1")).foreach(s => stringSetAccum += Set(s))
stringSetAccum.value.toString
res0: String = Set(2, 3, 1)
```

In Spark 2.0 you're probably fine with using the existing collectionAccumulator (if you care about distinct values, you can check and add only if they don't exist):

```
val collAcc = spark.sparkContext.collectionAccumulator[String]("myCollAcc")
collAcc: org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator[String] = CollectionAccumulator(id: 32154, name: Some(myCollAcc), value: [])

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array("1", "2", "3")).foreach(s => collAcc.add(s))

collAcc.value.toString
res0: String = [3, 2, 1]
```

More info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2